Extra vertical space when using \only and \onslide
The vertical space between some text and the image-B is a little bigger than that between some text and image-A.
Where does this extra space come from? I'd like to eliminate it.
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  some text
  \only<1>{%
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
  \end{center}
  }%
  \onslide<2->{%
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
  \end{center}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


\only and \onslide do different things in different context and from each other.
\only<overlay spec>{<stuff>} throws <stuff> away on non-specified slides. So it takes no space.
\onslide<overlay spec>{<stuff>} is equivalent to \uncover<overlay spec>{<stuff>}, so <stuff> still takes space but is, by default, invisible.
You can see this if you look in the .log after or on the console during compilation.
<example-image-a.pdf, id=13, 321.2pt x 240.9pt>
File: example-image-a.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-a.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-a.pdf  used on input line 16.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 307.28987pt x 230.47473pt.

OK, that's the image on the first slide, but the page hasn't shipped out yet.
<example-image-b.pdf, id=14, 321.2pt x 240.9pt>
File: example-image-b.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-b.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-b.pdf  used on input line 16.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 307.28987pt x 230.47473pt.

Here we see the second image on the first slide. Since there is not room for both, LaTeX complains:
Overfull \vbox (219.40285pt too high) detected at line 16
 []



[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} </usr/lo
cal/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.pdf> </usr/local/texl
ive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b.pdf>]

That's the first slide finished. In contrast, the first image is not used on the second slide:
File: example-image-b.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use example-image-b.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: example-image-b.pdf  used on input line 16.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 307.28987pt x 230.47473pt.


[2

]

So on the first slide, the stretchy space inserted between the text and the first image is minimised because there is too much stuff for the space and TeX minimises whatever it is allowed to minimise.
On the second slide, there is more than enough room for the text and single image, so the stretchy space is allowed to expand a bit and you get more vertical space between the text and the image.
Obviously you should not eliminate that vertical space by overfilling the second slide as well as the first. Rather, you should avoid overfilling the first slide.
Replacing \onslide<2->{<stuff>} with \onslide*<2->{<stuff>} will prevent <stuff> from being added to the first slide. Equivalently, you could just use \only<2->{<stuff>} here, as well.
That results in consistent vertical spacing, but it is consistently like the second of your slides rather than the first.
IMHO, the additional spacing makes for a slide which is visually more balanced and easier to read. However, if you do not want it, you can force content to be squeezed in various ways. For example, adding
\vfill
\mbox{}%

at the bottom will do the trick as TeX will prioritise letting \vfill expand into the available space. You may also want to use the t option either for this slide or your presentation, to top-align slides rather than vertically centring them. However, that does not change the spacing between elements of the contents, but only the overall vertical alignment of the contents as a whole.
% \begin{frame}[t]
\begin{frame}
  some text
  \only<1>{%
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{center}%
  }%
  \onslide*<2->{%
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
  \end{center}}
\end{frame}


\includegraphics is overlay-aware. This means you don't actually need to deal with \only, \onslide etc.:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  some text
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}%
    \includegraphics<2->[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}%
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Yeah. This makes the code much cleaner.
